# ElGamal encryption example?

Tags: c++, crypto++, elgamal

I apologise in advance for the n00bishness of asking this question, but I've been stuck for ages and I'm struggling to figure out what to do next. Essentially, I am trying to perform ElGamal encryption on some data. I have been given the public part of an ephemeral key pair and a second static key, as well as some data. If my understanding is correct, this is all I need to perform the encryption, but I'm struggling to figure out how using Crypto++.

I've looked endlessly for examples, but I can find literally zero on Google. Ohloh is less than helpful as I just get back endless pages of the cryptopp ElGamal source files, which I can't seem to be able to figure out (I'm relatively new to using Crypto++ and until about 3 days ago hadn't even heard of ElGamal).

The closest I've been able to find as an example comes from the CryptoPP package itself, which is as follows:

```
bool ValidateElGamal()
{
    cout << "\nElGamal validation suite running...\n\n";
    bool pass = true;
    {
        FileSource fc("TestData/elgc1024.dat", true, new HexDecoder);
        ElGamalDecryptor privC(fc);
        ElGamalEncryptor pubC(privC);
        privC.AccessKey().Precompute();
        ByteQueue queue;
        privC.AccessKey().SavePrecomputation(queue);
        privC.AccessKey().LoadPrecomputation(queue);

        pass = CryptoSystemValidate(privC, pubC) && pass;
    }
    return pass;
}
```

However, this doesn't really seem to help me much as I'm unaware of how to plug in my already computed values. I am not sure if I'm struggling with my understanding of how Elgamal works (entirely possible) or if I'm just being an idiot when it comes to using what I've got with CryptoPP. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been given the public part of an ephemeral key pair and a second static key, as well as some data.

We can't really help you here because we know nothing about what is supposed to be done.

The ephemeral key pair is probably for simulating key exchange, and the static key is long term for signing the ephemeral exchange. Other than that, its anybody's guess as to what's going on.

Would you happen to know what the keys are? is the ephemeral key a Diffie-Hellman key and the static key an ElGamal signing key?

---

> If my understanding is correct, this is all I need to perform the encryption, but I'm struggling to figure out how using Crypto++.

For the encryption example, I'm going to cheat a bit and use an [RSA encryption example](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) and port it to ElGamal. This is about as difficult as copy and paste because both RSA encryption and [ElGamal encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_el_gamal.html) adhere to the the `PK_Encryptor` and `PK_Decryptor` interfaces. See the [`PK_Encryptor`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___encryptor.html) and [`PK_Decryptor`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___decryptor.html) classes for details. (And keep in mind, you might need an ElGamal or Nyberg-Rueppel (NR) signing example).

Crypto++ has a cryptosystem built on ElGamal. The cryptosystem will encrypt a large block of plain text under a symmetric key, and then encrypt the symmetric key under the ElGamal key. I'm not sure what standard it follows, though (likely IEEE's P1363). See `SymmetricEncrypt` and `SymmetricDecrypt` in [elgamal.h](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/elgamal_8h_source.html).

The key size is artificially small so the program runs quickly. ElGamal is a discrete log problem, so its key size should be 2048-bits or higher in practice. 2048-bits is blessed by ECRYPT (Asia), ISO/IEC (Worldwide), NESSIE (Europe), and NIST (US).

If you need to save/persist/load the keys you generate, then see [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) on the Crypto++ wiki. The short answer is to call `decryptor.Save()` and `decryptor.Load()`; and stay away from the `{BER|DER}` encodings.

If you want, you can use a standard `string` rather than a `SecByteBlock`. The `string` will be easier if you are interested in printing stuff to the terminal via `cout` and friends.

Finally, there's now a page on the Crypto++ Wiki covering the topic with the source code for the program below. See Crypto++'s [ElGamal Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ElGamal).

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

#include <cryptopp/secblock.h>
using CryptoPP::SecByteBlock;

#include <cryptopp/elgamal.h>
using CryptoPP::ElGamal;
using CryptoPP::ElGamalKeys;

#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
using CryptoPP::DecodingResult;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Generate keys
    AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

    cout << "Generating private key. This may take some time..." << endl;

    ElGamal::Decryptor decryptor;
    decryptor.AccessKey().GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 512);
    const ElGamalKeys::PrivateKey& privateKey = decryptor.AccessKey();

    ElGamal::Encryptor encryptor(decryptor);
    const PublicKey& publicKey = encryptor.AccessKey();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Secret to protect
    static const int SECRET_SIZE = 16;
    SecByteBlock plaintext( SECRET_SIZE );
    memset( plaintext, 'A', SECRET_SIZE );

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Encrypt

    // Now that there is a concrete object, we can validate
    assert( 0 != encryptor.FixedMaxPlaintextLength() );
    assert( plaintext.size() <= encryptor.FixedMaxPlaintextLength() );

    // Create cipher text space
    size_t ecl = encryptor.CiphertextLength( plaintext.size() );
    assert( 0 != ecl );
    SecByteBlock ciphertext( ecl );

    encryptor.Encrypt( rng, plaintext, plaintext.size(), ciphertext );

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Decrypt

    // Now that there is a concrete object, we can check sizes
    assert( 0 != decryptor.FixedCiphertextLength() );
    assert( ciphertext.size() <= decryptor.FixedCiphertextLength() );

    // Create recovered text space
    size_t dpl = decryptor.MaxPlaintextLength( ciphertext.size() );
    assert( 0 != dpl );
    SecByteBlock recovered( dpl );

    DecodingResult result = decryptor.Decrypt( rng, ciphertext, ciphertext.size(), recovered );

    // More sanity checks
    assert( result.isValidCoding );
    assert( result.messageLength <= decryptor.MaxPlaintextLength( ciphertext.size() ) );

    // At this point, we can set the size of the recovered
    //  data. Until decryption occurs (successfully), we
    //  only know its maximum size
    recovered.resize( result.messageLength );

    // SecByteBlock is overloaded for proper results below
    assert( plaintext == recovered );

    // If the assert fires, we won't get this far.
    if(plaintext == recovered)
        cout << "Recovered plain text" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failed to recover plain text" << endl;

    return !(plaintext == recovered);
}
```

You can also create the `Decryptor` from a `PrivateKey` like so:

```
ElGamalKeys::PrivateKey k;
k.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 512);
ElGamal::Decryptor d(k);
...
```

And an `Encryptor` from a `PublicKey`:

```
ElGamalKeys::PublicKey pk;
privateKey.MakePublicKey(pk);
ElGamal::Encryptor e(pk);
```

---

You can save and load keys to and from disk as follows:

```
ElGamalKeys::PrivateKey privateKey1;
privateKey1.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 2048);
privateKey1.Save(FileSink("elgamal.der", true /*binary*/).Ref());

ElGamalKeys::PrivateKey privateKey2;
privateKey2.Load(FileSource("elgamal.der", true /*pump*/).Ref());
privateKey2.Validate(prng, 3);

ElGamal::Decryptor decryptor(privateKey2);
// ...
```

The keys are ASN.1 encoded, so you can dump them with something like Peter Gutmann's `dumpasn1`:

```
$ ./cryptopp-elgamal-keys.exe
Generating private key. This may take some time...
$ dumpasn1 elgamal.der 
  0 556: SEQUENCE {
  4 257:   INTEGER
       :     00 C0 8F 5A 29 88 82 8C 88 7D 00 AE 08 F0 37 AC
       :     FA F3 6B FC 4D B2 EF 5D 65 92 FD 39 98 04 C7 6D
       :     6D 74 F5 FA 84 8F 56 0C DD B4 96 B2 51 81 E3 A1
       :     75 F6 BE 82 46 67 92 F2 B3 EC 41 00 70 5C 45 BF
       :     40 A0 2C EC 15 49 AD 92 F1 3E 4D 06 E2 89 C6 5F
       :     0A 5A 88 32 3D BD 66 59 12 A1 CB 15 B1 72 FE F3
       :     2D 19 DD 07 DF A8 D6 4C B8 D0 AB 22 7C F2 79 4B
       :     6D 23 CE 40 EC FB DF B8 68 A4 8E 52 A9 9B 22 F1
       :             [ Another 129 bytes skipped ]
265   1:   INTEGER 3
268 257:   INTEGER
       :     00 BA 4D ED 20 E8 36 AC 01 F6 5C 9C DA 62 11 BB
       :     E9 71 D0 AB B7 E2 D3 61 37 E2 7B 5C B3 77 2C C9
       :     FC DE 43 70 AE AA 5A 3C 80 0A 2E B0 FA C9 18 E5
       :     1C 72 86 46 96 E9 9A 44 08 FF 43 62 95 BE D7 37
       :     F8 99 16 59 7D FA 3A 73 DD 0D C8 CA 19 B8 6D CA
       :     8D 8E 89 52 50 4E 3A 84 B3 17 BD 71 1A 1D 38 9E
       :     4A C4 04 F3 A2 1A F7 1F 34 F0 5A B9 CD B4 E2 7F
       :     8C 40 18 22 58 85 14 40 E0 BF 01 2D 52 B7 69 7B
       :             [ Another 129 bytes skipped ]
529  29:   INTEGER
       :     01 61 40 24 1F 48 00 4C 35 86 0B 9D 02 8C B8 90
       :     B1 56 CF BD A4 75 FE E2 8E 0B B3 66 08
       :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response, I really appreciate the effort you've put in there (And I'm really appreciative of the wiki entry, I think that'll be great for everyone). As it turns out, the requirements from our customer changed (or rather, when they said "Elgamel" what they actually meant was "Diffie-Helman" and somehow made the same mistake in about 15 different places and referenced various ElGamel specs and everything.). In any case, that might explain why what I said made no sense at all.

I have left this up because I'm sure it'll be a useful post to many and I may need it eventually.